# Finding the product of all numbers in a string of numbers using pl sql Recursive function

Tags: oracle, plsql

1. Finding the product of all the numbers of the string consisting of numbers using the recursive function,
2. The desired structure should be as follows.

   ```
   myfunction('3535') --> 225
   ```

Comment: Can you add the code you already tried?

Comment: It's not the code I'm bothered with, but the fact that I have no idea what the problem is. What "product"? Which "numbers"? Why "recursive function"?

Comment: the product of the digits of an integer entered into the function
I do not know why it is recursive. The teacher asked.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction_2 (v_integer IN integer)
   RETURN integer
IS
   
   v_result integer;
BEGIN

  WHILE n != 0  
   LOOP
            v_result := v_integer * (n % 10);
            n := n / 10;
   END LOOP;


      RETURN v_result;
END;

SELECT myfunction_2(3535) FROM DUAL;

Comment: Aha, THAT product! I thought / misunderstood that 3535 is a product code, representing some "product" (e.g. a *chair*) ...

Comment: Just for clarification, `3535` is a number. `3`,`5`,`3` and `5` are digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION product_of_digits(
  value IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68282548/1509264
  -- License: CC BY-SA 4.0

  IF value IS NULL THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  ELSE
    RETURN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(value, 1, 1))
      * COALESCE(product_of_digits(SUBSTR(value, 2)), 1);
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(product_of_digits('3535'));
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 225
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e44c217a75520f4866b62c147e19c9c6)*

Comment: firstly thank you,why did you use SUBSTR and COALESCE?

Comment: `SUBSTR` because the input is a string and you want the individual characters of the string; `COALESCE` because you need to handle the base case when the return value is `NULL` and want to multiply by `1` and not `NULL`.